# OTA update multiple times

Tags: rom, ota-update

I am using Xiaomi mobile which is unrooted. In that I have installed developer ROM. The manufacturer releases weekly updates, which is twice in week.

My question is that, Will it creates any software/hardware problems to the device after updating/installing several times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't mentioned your device but being a  question on frequent updates was browsing Xiaomi forums and here is a very similar question for Redmi Note 3 [asked and answered yesterday](http://en.miui.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=300232&highlight=updates)- you need to sign up

**Question asked (edited)**

> But getting "Updates available" message very often and none of them are less than 125MB and almost all of them are Stable.
>
> Two weeks back i got an update. I did it. And today (26th June - 2016) one more update. Called "Bug fixes".
>
> Why am i getting this often? Is that only me? Should i go for it?

**Reply from MIUI device team**

> Updates are normally to fix issues so is generally good to install them. If you are on the Stable ROM you should not get updates that often but **the Developer ROM can be a few a month**.
>
> Updates to the System get installed in the System partition not user areas anyway but generally they overwrite existing files anyway so does not use extra space anyway.

So you have it from the OEM that it is **safe**, and being on **developer ROM**, you should expect and get frequent updates

Answer (score 2):

"Will it creates any software/hardware problems to the device after updating/installing several times"
 - No.

These days, android security patches are being released every month. So, it is common to get monthly updates, although xiomi releases weekly updates. These updates are intended to fix the known issues and includes some security patches. For further information regarding the updates, you can refer to the update log, which is provided along with the update.